# How to display a PDF (w/hyperlinks) in an iPhone app like GoodReader?

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview

All I need to know is how to put a PDF page into a UIWebView, and then retrieve the URL value (into an NSString) of a link when clicked. Can somebody please offer their knowledge on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most iPhone PDF viewers are using CGPDF to render the PDF content.

To implement features like hyperlinks (AFIK hyperlinks in PDF are done via a "link annotation" tag, but there may be some other way), the PDF viewer uses the CGPDF API to scan/parse the PDF content stream for a given page, pull out any data it is interested in, then implement support for that feature.

So for hyperlinks, a viewer may use CGPDF to render the page in a view.  It would also use CGPDF to scan the page looking for link annotations, and pull out any attributes it needed (contents, destination, coordinates, etc.)  It would implement a touch-handler for the view and any code to execute when a user tapped the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if you render PDFs in  UIWebView.

Comment: Is my only option CGPDF then? How do you think GoodReader or other like apps are doing this?